# How can I deploy/import/install an SSIS project in SQL Server 2012 (Integration Services) without using the "Deploy" option im SQL Data Server Tools?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, ssis

I have a working SSIS project locally done by me with SQL Server Data Tools. I found out that the easiest way to have the project deployed in SQL Server is using the option "deploy", available on that IDE. I have done it successfully locally.

My problem is that I am not able to deploy the project directly to the client Server beacuse I have been ordered to give him no more than files, scripts , etc. in order to get the project deployed only by him. He cannot instal SQL Server Data Tools and deploy. I wonder if I can export my already deployed project in my local SQL Server instance and make him to import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give him the `.ispac` file from your SSDT project's `/bin` folder, and he will be able to [import it to the SQL Server using SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: are u sure about this?

Comment: @tylkonachwile That's how we do it here.   Why?

Comment: sounds incredibly simply, Lately I had this problem too and couldn&amp;#39;t find a solution. If this works I&amp;#39;ll kill myself :o

Comment: YES YES YES, that's the way i has to be done! without sql server data tools.

Comment: @tylkonachwile please give my regrets to your next of kin.  :)